# Boxcast in Unity2d not working as intended

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm currently trying to use a `Physics2D.BoxCast()` to manually detect collisions in a test project.  I got everything set up with the help of a tutorial I watched a while ago but for some reason the box cast seems to be above the Box Collider that I attached its size to.  I'm not the best a writing issues out so Ill have a gif bellow that better shows what the problem is, as well as I'll attach the code I used to detect the collisions.

[This is when I try to collide from +y on the axis](https://gyazo.com/0ccbfae94a859d49fefa982a40756809)

[This is when I try to collide from -y on the axis:](https://gyazo.com/7c68156275e119973b321373e691d643)

I've tried looking up more on how `Physics2D.BoxCast` work and why it would seem to be pushed down but I havent found anything helpful just yet.

Here's the code I use for movement and manual collision detection.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 2f;

    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;
    private Vector3 moveDelta;
    private RaycastHit2D hit2D;

    protected virtual void Awake() {
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    protected virtual void Update() {
        float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        moveDelta = new Vector3(x, y, 0);

        // Flips the sprite based on the direction its moving on the X
        if (moveDelta.x > 0)
        {
            sprite.flipX = false;
        }
        if (moveDelta.x < 0)
        {
            sprite.flipX = true;
        }

        // Manual detection for collisions
        hit2D = Physics2D.BoxCast(transform.position, boxCollider.size, 0, new Vector2(moveDelta.x, 0), Mathf.Abs(moveDelta.x * Time.deltaTime), LayerMask.GetMask("Blocking", "Actor"));
        if (hit2D.collider == null)
        {
            transform.Translate(moveDelta.x * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
        
        hit2D = Physics2D.BoxCast(transform.position, boxCollider.size, 0, new Vector2(0, moveDelta.y), Mathf.Abs(moveDelta.y * Time.deltaTime), LayerMask.GetMask("Blocking", "Actor"));
        if (hit2D.collider == null)
        {
            transform.Translate(0, moveDelta.y * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the unity3D tag I tried to edit it to Unity2D twice and it wont seem to change..

Answer (score 0):

The `transform.position` used in the box cast was not at the center of the collider.  Thus casting the `BoxCast` above where the collider was.  The solution was to place an empty game object in the center of the collider. Again I'm sorry about the way I explain things I hope the pictures bellow can help you understand better..

[image: The transform.postion as can be seem here is above the center of the BoxCollider2D]

[image: Using the position of this empty GameObject I could get the center of the CoxCollider2D]

Code wise it was a simple fix that took me too long to figure out..

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 2f;
    public GameObject boxcastCenter;

    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;
    private Vector3 moveDelta;
    private RaycastHit2D hit2D;

    protected virtual void Awake() {
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    protected virtual void Update() {
        float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        moveDelta = new Vector3(x, y, 0);

        // Flips the sprite based on the direction its moving on the X
        if (moveDelta.x > 0)
        {
            sprite.flipX = false;
        }
        if (moveDelta.x < 0)
        {
            sprite.flipX = true;
        }

        // Manual detection for collisions changes were made in the transform.position bellow
        hit2D = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxcastCenter.transform.position, boxCollider.size, 0, new Vector2(moveDelta.x, 0), Mathf.Abs(moveDelta.x * Time.deltaTime), LayerMask.GetMask("Blocking", "Actor"));
        if (hit2D.collider == null)
        {
            transform.Translate(moveDelta.x * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
        
        hit2D = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxcastCenter.transform.position, boxCollider.size, 0, new Vector2(0, moveDelta.y), Mathf.Abs(moveDelta.y * Time.deltaTime), LayerMask.GetMask("Blocking", "Actor"));
        if (hit2D.collider == null)
        {
            transform.Translate(0, moveDelta.y * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
    }
}
```